# Do multiple resistances combine into immunity?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, damage-resistance, immunities

If my character for D&D has resistance to spells and magical damage (a yuan-ti) and if a class feature also gives resistance to spells and magical damage, does that mean my character would have immunity to spells and magical damage?

Comment: What edition of D&D are you asking about? Different edition have different rules and we can't provide an answer without knowing which rules we're looking at.

Comment: This sounds like 5th edition D&D. Is that correct?